# Mongoose hide fields AFTER populating

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, populate, typegoose

Supposed I have this schema

```
class Room {
  member_ids: [String]
  owner_ids: [String]
}
```

And two virtual populates `members` and `owners`, which map to `User` schema (custom path, not `_id`)

I successfully get the data populated with this:

```
return this.roomModel
      .findOne({ id: roomId })
      .select('-_id -__v')
      .populate('members owners', '-_id -__v')
      .exec();
```

It now returns

```
{
    "member_ids": [
        "1",
        "2"
    ],
    "owner_ids": [
        "1"
    ],
    "owners": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "User 1"
        }
    ],
    "members": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "User 1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "User 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

The thing is, I don't want `member_ids` and `owner_ids` to end up in my response. I've tried using `select('-member_ids -owner_ids')` however the response did not have populated data anymore (I guess the `select` phase happens before the `populate` phase?). Is there anyway to achieve this, without resorting to manually removing the fields afterwards? Thank you.

Comment: I afraid it's not possible because mongoose use multiple query to return populated result. In your case, one main query to get room and two queries using `member_ids`, `owner_ids` from the result of the main query to get `owners` and `members`. So you need to have `member_ids` and `owner_ids` in the result of the first query.

Comment: Thank you. So there's no way to 'hide' fields after populating the result, other than manually deleting the `member_ids` and `owner_ids` keys?

Comment: Not sure but I guess no.